# neo4j web admin not viewable even with 0.0.0.0 enabled

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j, mediatemple

Even with org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0 enabled, I still am not able to view the web admin neo4j browser interface from an external machine.

The neo4j database is currently showing as running when using the command service neo4j-service status.

I am using a DV developer account hosted by Media Temple.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the setup of your machine and/or the network infrastructure, you need to setup an appropriate firewall rule to enable access to tcp port 7474 from outside.